# Install module in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript2.0

I'm going to install and use [victory-native](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native) module in typescript. I tried `npm install @types/victory-native` but it says there's no module `@types/victory-native`.

Should I install only `@types/...` module in typescript?

How can I use this module in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `npm install victory-native --save`
This module do not have typing, but there's nothing to stop you from using it.
You also need to install the dependency manually, and then link native code
`react-native link react-native-svg`.

Please refer to their guide:
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native

**Update**
In case, you are not familiar with how to work with native module and TypeScript.
There is my way for this case:

- When you see it requires link, it's easy to work with an ejected app, rather than expo. Assuming the project was created from `create-react-native-app`. Make sure the project is ejected by run `yarn eject`
- run `yarn add victory-native react-native-svg` to install module
- In tsconfig.json, set `"allowJs": true, "noImplicitAny": false`.
- After `react-native link react-native-svg`, open Android Studio, in **build.gradle(Module: app)** file, Try find `dependencies { compile project(':react-native-svg') ... }` at the bottom. Add this line, if it's not exist.
- Under **android** folder, run `gradlew clean` in command line.
- Then build your js files, and run `react-native run-android` from command line. This module should work now.

There is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "filesGlob": ["typings/index.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "types": ["react", "react-native", "jest"],
  "exclude": ["android", "ios", "build", "node_modules"],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

A simple example directly copied from [official documentation](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { VictoryBar } from "victory-native";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <VictoryBar />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: But I get error when I import, `Could not find a declaration file for module 'victory-native'. “../node_modules/victory-native/lib/index.js” implicitly has an 'any' type. Try npm install @types/victory-native if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'victory-native';`

Comment: Yeah, `const Victory = require("victory-native");` helped me instead of `import`.

Comment: Awesome. Please mention about importing - "require" and I'll check your answer.

Comment: `import * as Victory from "victory-native"` is the preferred syntax in TypeScript.